# Google spreadsheet - set row background color depending on the user

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

There are three users(x1, x2, x3) used to update their daily reports, username are there in column2. For x1 user set background color of the entire row set to red and accordingly for the other two user (blue, green).

I hope the error is in getting the entire row, i don't know how to solve, please help.

Thank you.

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i][1]=="X1") {
    var headersRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 7);
      headersRange.setBackgroundColor(red);
    }   
    else if(data[i][1]=="X2") {
      var headersRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 7);
      headersRange.setBackgroundColor(blue);
    }    
    else if(data[i][1]=="X3") {
      var headersRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 7);
      headersRange.setBackgroundColor(green);
    }
    else {
      var headersRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 7);
      headersRange.setBackgroundColor(white);      
    }

  }
 }
```

Comment: Hello naren, I downvoted your question because for me it does not show any research effort. I hope it's not misunderstood, but in my opinion you are supposed to try to do the job by your own not to ask others to do it for you.

Comment: Suggest you have a look at the google apps script examples/docs and then update the question. Also add the google-apps-script tag.

Comment: Hello Harold, i did my research but i can't get what i needed. Please don't underestimate other people easily. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Harold's point is that you didn't show what you had researched (for example, linking some Stack Overflow solutions that you tried, but they didn't work for what you needed).  This was good practice for me to think outside the box of your code, so I made something.  Here is the example spreadsheet and code:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Amp9JhtmHqC8dE95U1dweXBMNjNhRmpQQURnZ1FoMFE#gid=0

But, I'll give you an answer, hoping that you'll do some more research to see why it works:

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  //getRange starts on row 2, since I put column headers on row 1
  var data = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow(),7).getValues();
  //column headers are on row 1, data.length +1 offsets for header row
  for (var i = 2; i < data.length+1; i++) {
    switch (sheet.getRange(i,1,1,1).getValue()){
      case "X1":
        sheet.getRange(i,1,1,7).setBackgroundColor('red')
        break;
      case "X2":
        sheet.getRange(i,1,1,7).setBackgroundColor('blue')
        break;
      case "X3":
        sheet.getRange(i,1,1,7).setBackgroundColor('green')
        break;
      default:
        sheet.getRange(i,1,1,7).setBackgroundColor('white')
        break;
    }
  }
}
```